# show "flock: Command not found" when install node.js on QNAP NAS

Tags: linux, node.js, flock, qnap

I want to install node.js on QNAP NAS, it's a linux OS I can use ipkg install package.
but ipkg not have node.js...

I reference web forum as http://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?p=248556, installed V8 JavaScript Engine.

Then install node.js

When I'm typing **make** on /opt/node, that shows an error message as follows:

> make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1 make[1]: Entering directory
>   `/share/HDA_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/node/out'   flock
>   /share/HDA_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/node/out/Release/linker.lock g++
>   -pthread -rdynamic   -o /share/HDA_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/node/out/Release/mksnapshot
>   -Wl,--start-group /share/HDA_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/node/out/Release/obj.target/mksnapshot/deps/v8/src/mksnapshot.o
>   /share/HDA_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/v8/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a
>   /share/HDA_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/node/out/Release/obj.target/deps/v8/tools/gyp/libv8_nosnapshot.a
>   -Wl,--end-group make[1]: flock: Command not found make[1]: *** [/share/HDA_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/node/out/Release/mksnapshot] Error 127
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`/share/HDA_DATA/.qpkg/Optware/node/out'
>   make: *** [node] Error 2

The QNAP NAS(TS-119P2) does not have flock command line,
What can I do? Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 4):

```
ipkg install util-linux
```

It contains flock command.

Goto node source dir.

```
./configure --prefix=/opt
...

LINK=g++ make
...

LINK=g++ make install
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had to export CC as my compiler, and then run the commands babalooi suggested:

```
export CC=/opt/bin/gcc
./configure --prefix=/opt
```

...

```
LINK=g++ make
```

...

```
LINK=g++ make install
```